# Using new [className] without a return

Tags: c#, class, test-automation

I have started using the following in my automation code in instances where I'm not interested in keeping the object 'alive'and just using it as a means as a type of precondition.  For example:

Instead of the following:

```
Login login = new Login()
login.SetUserName(username).SetPassword(password).Submit()
```

I do the following instead (as an example!):

```
new Login().SetUserName(username).SetPassword(myPassword).Submit()
```

In the above example, what is this technique called, and is it wise to use it in the way that I'm doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Are there any actual drawbacks to self-referential method chaining?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80244/118878)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any actual drawbacks to self-referential method chaining?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80244/are-there-any-actual-drawbacks-to-self-referential-method-chaining)

Answer (score 1):

It's called [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and it's neither generally bad nor good, it depends on the implementation.

Personally I don't think your example adds anything in readability over your own example or even just:

```
 var login = new Login();
     login.SetUserName(username);
     login.SetPassword(myPassword);
     login.Submit();
```

The main point of "fluent" is readability and type-safety in combining options.

---

One question would be, does this:

```
new Login().SetUserName(username).SetPassword(myPassword).Submit()
```

add anything over the static method

```
Login.Submit(username, password);
```

If it does (for example because it has different overloads for the Login constructor to inject another HTTP client or something like that) then great. If not, I would wonder why you make it so complicated.

Comment: I've updated my question.  Hopefully I've made it clearer.

Comment: As per the article you link to, it's called a *fluent* interface, not a fluid one ;)

Comment: @DavidArno lol, you're right, I mixed that up, same word in my native language :)

Answer (score 0):

From the compiler's point of view, your two versions are no different. The `login` variable will just be optimised away in the first example as it's not needed. So really, it just becomes a matter of personal style as to which you use.

A third option is to replace the `new Login()` with a static method that returns the `login` object for your fluent interface, eg:

```
Login.Create().SetUserName(username).SetPassword(myPassword).Submit();
```

but again, this is very much a style thing. There's no correct way to do this and there's no specific terms to distinguish your two approaches.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input and suggestions - very helpful.  Unfortunately, I can't upvote as my reputation score does not allow me.